# PDF: how to interpret names not listed on Adobe Glyph List

Tags: parsing, pdf, encoding, fonts, character-encoding

While parsing different PDF files I face up glyph names not listed on [Adobe Glyph List](https://github.com/adobe-type-tools/agl-aglfn) in font encodings (specifically in *Font.Encoding.Differences*)

For example: *budleafboldsw*

Any recommendations how to interpret ones (empty strings, nulls, string entities)?

Refer to Adobe docs/specs if possible please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Adobe Glyph List Specification](https://github.com/adobe-type-tools/agl-specification#3-examples) says that such names are mapped to empty strings:

> The name ‘foo’ maps to an empty string, because ‘foo’ is not in AGL, and because it does not start with a ‘u’.